# By whom is the Trump "Immunity case" presently stayed

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court, process

[had been posted to politics.stackexchange.com, but comments there indicated it would be more appropriate here]

According to a number of YouTube videos, when a case is appealed to the Supreme Court, the Court may initially decide on two separate issues:

1. Whether it will grant or deny certiorari.  If *four* or more judges vote in favor *of granting cert*, cert will be granted.  Otherwise, cert will be denied.
2. Whether to stay the earlier court's judgment.  If *five* or more judges vote in favor *of granting a stay* until final judgment, the earlier court's judgment will be stayed.  Otherwise it will not.

A decision to hear a case does not imply any judgment as to whether the appeal has any merit; sometimes the Court may hear a case for the purpose of granting its "stamp of approval" on the lower court's judgment.  On the other hand, judges are only supposed to vote in favor of a stay if a variety of conditions are met, including a belief that the appeal is likely to succeed on the merits.

The Supreme Court's [order](https://www.supremecourt.gov/orders/courtorders/022824zr3_febh.pdf) granting cert, however, contains the following:

> Without expressing a view on the merits, this Court directs the Court of Appeals to continue withholding issuance of the mandate until the sending down of the judgment of this Court.  The application for a stay is dismissed as moot.

By what authority is that direction issued?  According to the videos I've seen, issuance of a stay is supposed to require--among other things--a finding that an appeal would likely succeed on the merits, a finding that the Court has *expressly stated* that it has not made.  Is the Court simply indicating that its decision should not be viewed as fulfilling the conditions upon which the lower court's stay would naturally vacate itself, but leaving open the possibility of the lower court's stay being vacated via other means, such as an explicit motion?